# Will my code work on an Android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm new to Android. This is my first wear compatible app. I know this is a very silly question, but I don't know if my code below works on wear or not (I don't have a real device).

```
    public class MainWearActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    // record the compass picture angle turned
    private float currentDegree = 0f;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    ImageView image;
    TextView tvHeading;
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // for the system's orientation sensor registered listeners
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // to stop the listener and save battery
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
        float degree = event.values[0];
        if (Math.round(degree) == 360) {
            tvHeading.setText("0°");
        }else{
            tvHeading.setText(Math.round(degree) + "°");
        }
        // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree, -degree, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        // how long the animation will take place
        ra.setDuration(210);
        // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
        ra.setFillAfter(true);
        // Start the animation
        currentDegree = -degree;
        image.startAnimation(ra);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Not in use
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Now you can test apps that require sensors on an emulator by using *virtual sensors*.

Comment: Have you tried your code on a Android device (not Wear). At least you'll know the code is correct. After that the only real test would be on device.

Comment: Yes, i tested it on a phone and it worked, so than it will work on a wear too (which has the right sensors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an Android Wear. But you can have access to a simulator of Android Wear. Look at [Android Wear Emulator](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html).

Update your **SDK**, set up an **Android Wear Device** and you can test your app and verify your code by yourself.

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, i know, but i am not able to check the app without sensor data. I just wanted a confirmation if this is a correct code to get the sensor values on a wearable.

Comment: We can't definitively say your code will run as is by looking at it. But the sensor API in Wear is identical to that on other Android devices, so you can test that part of your code on a phone (and the rest on an emulator, as  @Français suggested).

Comment: A couple of other comments... If you're going to be doing Wear development, you really should get a device; some of the early models are quite cheap these days. Also, once you have a beta version of your app ready, you could share it on the Wear dev community on G+. Folks there are often willing to help beginning devs try it out on different hardware (within reason of course). https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/113381227473021565406

Comment: Nice comments, @String, I agree with your idea.